# Is there any function in MySQL for Regex Replace?

Tags: mysql, regex, string, replace

I have a table which needs stores some name and i need to replace a few characters before comparing them with another string

For instance, My table data is

---

```
abc
ghi:dki
ioe  dsa
```

---

i read a string from user, which is of the form `abc`, `ghi-dki`, `ioe-dsa`. ie, all blankspaces, multiples spaces and symbols are converted to a hyphon(-). Now i need to compare. something like

```
SELECT MYCOLUMN FROM MYTABLE WHERE {Converted MYCOLUMN} = 'ghi-dki'
```

Can someone help me for figuring out which MySQL function can do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do a regex replace in MySQL, but you can do a match.

```
SELECT mycolumn FROM tablename WHERE mycolumn REGEXP Replace('ghi-dki', '-', '^[\s:_-]*$');
```

Note: I didn't completely fill out the symbols character set, you'll have to add whatever you're using.